# Change of Index page based on subdomain/domain name

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts, project-planning

Problem and my idea on it is just vague as I'm still in design phase.  I just wanted to know something to get a head start on the problem and how/where to proceed to solve it.

Problem Part:

There's one web app built using struts-2 JSP/servlet, with the URL `mywebapp.com`.
The requirement is every client can access this `mywebapp.com` using their subdomain, like `webapp.abc.com,` `myapp.xyz.com,` etc. I have to filter based on the domain name to give them a customized login page. I have saved their domain name in the database to map their details that need to be displayed on customized login page.

What I have thought is they will give the IP address of `mywebapp.com` to their subdomain registry so it will land on `mywebapp.com,` but from here, how can I filter the domain/subdomain for a customized login page?

Any possible way to start on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a Filter.  With a filter, you can process any requests to your application independent of the controllers.

For instance, if you wanted to redirect to a different page based on subdomain, your filter could manage this, either as a filter that processes before the controller call or after the controller call.

**UPDATE:** There is more documentation on Struts 2 Interceptors, which can serve a similar purpose:  http://java.dzone.com/articles/struts2-tutorial-part-57

```
 String domain = "";
 String subdomain = "";

 String url = request.getRequestURL();
 String[] parts = url.split(".");

 // subdomain.domain.com  0, 1, 2
 // subdomain1.subdomain2.domain.com  0, 1, 2, 3
 domain = (parts.length - 2 > -1) ? parts[1] : parts[];

 for(int i = parts.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     if(i == parts.length - 2) {
         domain = parts[i];
     }
     if(i == parts.length - 3) {
         subdomain = parts[i];
     }
 }
```

If you start from the end of the array, you know that the 2nd to last is always the second-level domain (SLD) and the 3rd from last is where the third level subdomains will be.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I did consider interceptor but could not find any example even in book about filtering Domain name. if you happen to know can you please give a code snippet or any link of similar example.

Comment: request.getRequestURL() will solve my problem in interceptor or filter I'm going to check it as i don't have that setup yet thanks.

Comment: @rain - I added some code to get you started with the domain/subdomain extraction.  I assume you can handle the if branching based on the subdomain/domain values themselves :)