# How to return global result from custom action mapper in Struts2

Tags: java, struts2

How do you return a custom global result in custom action mapper.

```
public class MyCustomActionMapper implements ActionMapper {

  public ActionMapping getMapping(HttpServletRequest request, 
                                  ConfigurationManager configManager) {
    ....
    ....
    return ????
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure this is really what you need to do ? Struts2 gives you all the tools you need out-of-the-box, to achieve almost every result.

But if you really want to implement your Custom Action Mapper, then take a look at the Chapter 9, pages from 266 to 269, of [Struts2 Web 2.0 Projects by Ian Roughley](http://books.google.it/books?id=HrFGgg3fPwsC&pg=PA266&dq=creating%20a%20custom%20action%20mapper&hl=it&sa=X&ei=aSbYULvnDKiK4gTko4CIBg&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=creating%20a%20custom%20action%20mapper&f=false);

> The ActionMapper interface provides two methods: one that converts a URL to an action mapping, and another that converts the other way, from an action mapping to a URL.

So, you map your Actions and your result types from struts.xml as usual, and not in your Action Mapper.

Take a look at the [DefaultActionMapper source code](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/struts/struts2-core/2.3.1.1/struts2-core-2.3.1.1-sources.jar!/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/mapper/DefaultActionMapper.java?format=ok) too... no result types anywhere, this is not where they are managed.

```
public ActionMapping getMapping(HttpServletRequest request,
                                ConfigurationManager configManager) {
    ActionMapping mapping = new ActionMapping();
    String uri = getUri(request);

    int indexOfSemicolon = uri.indexOf(";");
    uri = (indexOfSemicolon > -1) ? uri.substring(0, indexOfSemicolon) : uri;

    uri = dropExtension(uri, mapping);
    if (uri == null) {
        return null;
    }

    parseNameAndNamespace(uri, mapping, configManager);

    handleSpecialParameters(request, mapping);

    if (mapping.getName() == null) {
        return null;
    }

    parseActionName(mapping);

    return mapping;
}
```

Comment: Thanks fow the answear, I need to return some page, when a request has the wrong subdomain. Then have to do it through Interceptor

Comment: Absolutely, you can do it with Interceptors. Search on SO, it's full of answers on how to do that

Comment: This I know, I just did not want to create Interceptor for checking the correctness of the subdomain. Action mapper is already used for their own purposes, so I wanted to check subdomain in the Action Mapper

Comment: it's means, that subdomain is exist on our site (subdomains are regions of country)

Comment: Ok. You may want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779021/solvedchange-of-index-page-based-on-subdomain-domain-name

Answer (score 0):

ActionMapping getMapping(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request,
                         ConfigurationManager configManager)

```
Expose the ActionMapping for the current request

Parameters:
    request - The servlet request
    configManager - The current configuration manager 
Returns:
    The appropriate action mapping String or null if mapping cannot be determined
```

Comment: ie custom global result can not be returned, because global result is not a action. I understand correctly?